# Use of ps after awk without a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ps

I am trying to get the current number of running processes for each user on my machine, but I want to do it without a pipe command to get the same output.

I tried this and it works, but I want to use something like /bin/ps which doesn't work.

```
ps aux --noheader | awk '{count[$1]++}END{for (n in count) print count[n], n}'
```

The output for the command above is:

```
1 polkitd 
1 bus
2 avahi
89 root
```

I have been trying this:

```
awk ‘{count[$1]++}END{for (n in count) print count[n], n}’ /bin/ps
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is the purpose behind avoiding the pipe?  You could use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), I suppose: `awk '…' <(ps -aux --noheader)`, but there's no virtue in that compared with the pipeline that I can see.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I didn't use the brackets initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can used getline to populate a variable with the information, such as

```
 awk ' BEGIN {"who|wc -l"|getline users;print "Users logged on: " users}'
 Users logged on: 2
```

Comment: I didn't understand this properly because as fas as I know, getline would give the output of an entire line, whereas I want the first column in ps -aux. Though I would like you to give some more information.

Comment: This example generates a single line of output (containing a single column/value) from the command and reads it into an `awk` variable `users` and then prints it.  With the output from `ps`, you'd need a loop, and you'd want `awk` to split the incoming lines into words -- as shown in my example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid an explicit pipe symbol, you can either use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
awk '{count[$1]++}END{for (n in count) print count[n], n}' <(ps -aux --noheader)
```

or use `awk`'s `getline`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ("ps -aux --noheader" | getline) proc[$1]++
             for (user in proc) print user, proc[user] }'
```

The options to `ps` are not portable; they don't work at all on Mac OS X, for example, but when I tested with `-ef` instead of `-aux --noheader`, I got sane — or, at least, explicable — output.